# trigger.io ios module build error from template

Tags: trigger.io

I started a new private module but got a build error without touching any code.

[image: xcode 5.1.1 build error]

Error: framework not found WebKit

Any help would be great.

-Trav.

Comment: I to am having this exact same issue. WebKit isn't even available to be added.

Comment: Seems to back working now.